# How to create a local Object instance from the generic type

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanna know how can I create an instance of an `Object` from the passed generic Type `T` passed from the super class constructor

this example of what I want to achieve but it's wrong :

```
class Widget<T> extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget({super.key});

  final T instanceOfT = T(); // throws 'T' isn't a function.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(instanceOfT.exampleStringProperty);
  }
}

class ExampleClass {
  final String exampleStringProperty;
  const ExampleClass({this.exampleStringProperty = "exampleValue"});
}
```

I'm expecting  that I should pass the Type from the generic call when calling the Widget constructor like this:

```
Widget<ExampleClass>(),
```

Then an instance of the `ExampleClass` should be created and works fine.

Any ideas on this ?

Comment: You cannot.  This has been covered in many other questions.  Make your class take a *callback* that constructs and returns a `T` instead.

Comment: of I guess you're right, I searched and found a thing kind of a package called dart:mirrors, but I never saw someone talked about it or used it in a flutter app, do you have any information about this

Comment: @Gwhyyy, `dart:mirrors` isn't supported in Flutter for a variety of technical reasons, and is probably in a fairly broken state at this point since Dart 2.0 and null-safety were released.